# -60 rep, user removed. Who?

Tags: support, users

So, while watching feom the penaltybox, I noticed something strange In my rep. I know what happened, but

**Can I find the list of deleted users somewhere?** Because I want to know, what happened to that  person with a total 12 upvotes in my questions.

Comment: There is a Meta Post discussing this topic [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140063/user-was-removed-need-to-show-which-answer-question-loses-its-reputation). I think the essential part is this: "As Flexo pointed out in comments, this would also undermine the anonymity of voting. I don't see that sufficient advantage is gained by showing this information to offset this problem." [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it) general post might be interesting for you, too.

Comment: @Secesptius Oh, thanks.

Comment: "...what happened to that person..." -- Simple: his/her account was deleted.

Comment: I would add a comment that, users can delete their own accounts too, so be nice to newer users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't find out.  Votes are private, so revealing who was the source of your reputation changes from vote reversals would violate that.  In addition, users are allowed to leave quietly if they want, or if SE removes them for violating the terms of service.

See [this question on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470/162102) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140063/162102) for more about this topic.